# matplotlib scatterplot picker

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want a picker on `plot_date` but it is not responding on clicks. even other events will not connect to the graphs.

This class will get tweets from a local database for sentiment analyse.

[image: current screenshot programma]

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.dates as md
from matplotlib.dates import DayLocator, HourLocator, DateFormatter, drange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as Tk
from Core.Database import Database
from numpy import arange

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
plt.style.use('ggplot')

class SentimentGraph:
    figure = None
    axes = None

    timeStamps = []
    sentiment_score = []

    def __init__(self, create_figure=True):
        # get data from database.
        self.get_data()

        # create figure.
        if create_figure:
            self.figure = plt.figure()

        # draw graph in figure
        self.draw_graph(self.figure)

    def draw_graph(self, figure):

        neutral = 0
        negative = 0
        positive = 0

        for score in self.sentiment_score:
            if score == 0:
                neutral += 1
            elif score > 0:
                positive += 1
            elif score < 0:
                negative += 1

        self.figure, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1)
        ax1, ax2 = axes.ravel()

        # The slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise.
        labels = 'neutral', 'Negative', 'Positive'
        sizes = [neutral, positive, negative]
        colors = ['yellowgreen', 'lightcoral', 'lightskyblue']
        explode = (0, 0.1, 0.1)  # only "explode" the 2nd slice (i.e. 'Hogs')

        ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors,
                autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90,
                radius=0.25, center=(0, 0), frame=True)

        # Set aspect ratio to be equal so that pie is drawn as a circle.
        ax1.axis('equal')
        ax1.axis('off')

        ax2.plot_date(self.timeStamps, self.sentiment_score, alpha=0.5, picker=True)

        def onclick(event):
            index = event.ind
            xy = event.artist.get_offsets()
            print('--------------')
            print(xy[index])

        self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onclick)

        ax2.set_title("Sentiment score")
        ax2.set_ylabel("Sentiment score")
        xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

        ax2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(HourLocator(arange(0, 25, 6)))
        ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
        ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

        ax2.fmt_xdata = md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        self.figure.autofmt_xdate()

    def get_data(self):
        db = Database()
        result = db.query(
            ''' select sentiment_score, posted_at / 1000 as timestamp from tweets ''')
        rows = result.fetchall()

        for row in rows:
            self.sentiment_score.append(row[0])
            # convert unix timestamp to matplotlib compatible
            date = matplotlib.dates.epoch2num(row[1])
            self.timeStamps.append(date)
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # change config db file location
    import config

    config.DB_FILE = "../tweets.db"

    # create window
    root = Tk.Tk()
    root.wm_title("time line")

    graph = SentimentGraph()


    def _quit():
        root.quit()  # stops mainloop
        root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent
        # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate


    # a tk.DrawingArea
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph.figure, master=root)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, root)
    toolbar.update()
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    button = Tk.Button(master=root, text='Quit', command=_quit)
    button.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM)

    Tk.mainloop()
    # If you put root.destroy() here, it will cause an error if
    # the window is closed with the window manager.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you're not embedding your figure in your Tkinter application.

Instead, you're creating an entirely new tkinter widget and window when you call `plt.figure` or `plt.subplots`.  You're then "piggybacking" another canvas on top of that pre-existing figure and using it in your application.

Because matplotlib thinks the plot belongs to the original figure you created with `plt.subplots`, it's not registering any mouse events.

When you're embedding a figure in another application you must use the figure that you create manually. You cannot call `plt.figure` or `plt.subplots` (or `plt.anything`, really).

To solve your problem, set up the canvas inside your application using a manually-created `Figure` object, similar to the embedding examples in the documentation.